# regex in CloudWatch event pattern matching

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

How can I match a CloudWatch event on a regex. I need to invoke only a particular SNS target on a specific job name. e.g, something like below where I want to do a regex match on TranscriptionJobName. Thanks.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.transcribe"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Transcribe Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "TranscriptionJobStatus": [
      "COMPLETED",
      "FAILED"
    ],
    "TranscriptionJobName": [
      "transcription-localhost-*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to make something similar. Is there any progress on this?

Comment: @YaroslavTkachenko : I ended up creating separate rule for each target SNS topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating separate rule for each target SNS topic.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible with EventBridge and its [ability to do prefix matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html).  This works for me.  I have a Lambda function set up as a target, and the function is executed only upon a Transcribe job reaching `COMPLETED` status and having a job name starting with `voicemail-`.

```json
{
  "source": [
    "aws.transcribe"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "TranscriptionJobName": [
      {
        "prefix": "voicemail-"
      }
    ],
    "TranscriptionJobStatus": [
      "COMPLETED"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to solve this as well and it does not appear this is possible, given the following AWS documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html

> It is important to remember the following about event pattern
>   matching:
>
> - For a pattern to match an event, the event must contain all the field names listed in the pattern. The field names must appear in the
>     event with the same nesting structure.
> - Other fields of the event not mentioned in the pattern are ignored; effectively, there is a "*": "*" wildcard for fields not mentioned.
> - **The matching is exact (character-by-character), without case-folding or any other string normalization.**
> - The values being matched follow JSON rules: Strings enclosed in quotes, numbers, and the unquoted keywords true, false, and null.
> - Number matching is at the string representation level. For example, 300, 300.0, and 3.0e2 are not considered equal.

Bummer...

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out by using Numeric matching expression in the event pattern for Guard Duty findings something like below;

```
    {
      "detail": {
        "severity": [{
          "numeric": [">", 0, "<=", 8.9]
        }]
      },
      "detail-type": [
        "GuardDuty Finding"
      ],
      "source": [
        "aws.guardduty"
      ]
    }
```