# How to use regex on Cloudwatch Events

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, events, filter, amazon-cloudwatch

In a Cloudwatch Event, we can write filter rules on source, details etc. How I'm doing it currently is as
shown below,

```
  DefaultEventsRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: "CloudWatchRule1"
      Description: "Match events and send them to corresponding queue for delivery."
      EventPattern:
        {
          "source": ["xyz"],
          "resources":
              ...
```

Is it possible to do regex operation on that `source`?
It looks like it is not possible to write regex on events; there is another question out there in SO asking a similar question (for `destination`), and the workaround was to use separate rules, seems that is the only way for source too.

Ref: [regex-in-cloudwatch-event-pattern-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657189/regex-in-cloudwatch-event-pattern-matching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now RegEx is not supported. Maximum you can do is to use `complex filter` with `EventBridge`
See details [content-filtering-with-event-patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-complex-example).

Also see the answers in this SO question, [regex-in-cloudwatch-event-pattern-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54657189/regex-in-cloudwatch-event-pattern-matching) which helped me.

Hope AWS guys will add `RegEx matching` in future!